# Divi Builder issue : backend does not display

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using Divi theme version 3 on Wordpress, it includes the Divi builder, but I have an issue for few days : when I try to open a module on the backend, it does not display the settings (fields & other module elements).

This is all I got, all the other fields & elements are missing : [how modules are displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tExGl.png)

No updates done for plugins or worpdress before it occured, I disabled all plugins to check if there's a conflict, I reinstalled WordPress, swicthed the theme, deleted browsers cache & local storage.

Comment: are you using a child theme?

Comment: are you create custom module ?

Comment: no child theme and no custom module ! Divi theme is up to date and WP as well

Answer (score 0):

**PHP, MySQL and Apache Requirements**

- PHP 7 or greater
- MySQL 5.6 or greater
- The mod_rewrite Apache module

**PHP variable requirments**

```
post_max_size 128M (48 is enough)
upload_max_filesize 128M (32 is enough)
max_input_time 600 (120 is enough)
max_input_vars 3000 (1000 is enough)
PHP memory limit 128MB (96 is enough)
```

Also add this to the end of your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
SubstituteMaxLineLength 20M
</IfModule>
```

My suggestion is that you should update Divi to the latest version just to be sure. Worst case scenario you can do a Theme Rollback from the Updates tab in Theme Options but try the above first